# Vector fails to get initialized

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I am trying do initialize a vector of self-defined type `dataCard`:

```
vector<dataCard> dataSet;
dataSet.reserve(200);
```

However the compiler doesn't allow me to do that indicating an error at the second line (where I try to reserve space for the container):

```
required from here
```

However when I change the declaration to the following

```
vector<dataCard*> dataSet;
```

it starts working.

What could be the reason for the compiler not allowing me to use my type as it is, but letting me to use a pointer to the type? I actually need a vector of objects, not pointers to them.

EDIT

Header file of `dataCard`

```
#include <card.h>


class dataCard {
    char* name; // name according to the filename
    char Class; // Classes: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, T, J, Q, K, A
    double distanceToQuery;
public:
    void resetDistance();
    int numBlackTotal (bitmap* bmp);
    bitmap image;
    int numOfBlackPixels;
    char* getName();
    void setName(char* n);
    void setClass (char* c);
    char* getClass();
    void setDistance(double distance);
    double getDistance ();
    dataCard(const char* fname);
    dataCard();
    virtual ~dataCard();
};
```

Here's an error message from compiler

```
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:77:3:   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = dataCard*; _ForwardIterator = dataCard*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:119:41:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = dataCard*; _ForwardIterator = dataCard*]’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:260:63:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = dataCard*; _ForwardIterator = dataCard*; _Tp = dataCard]’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:1112:8:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_allocate_and_copy(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, _ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _ForwardIterator = dataCard*; _Tp = dataCard; _Alloc = std::allocator<dataCard>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = dataCard*; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/vector.tcc:76:70:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reserve(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = dataCard; _Alloc = std::allocator<dataCard>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
/home/ppsadm01/Documents/vgv/src/main.cc:145:22:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:85:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘dataCard::dataCard(const dataCard&)’
```

Comment: is `dataCard` copy-constructible?

Comment: The complete error message may also be helpful (for you and for SO).

Comment: Sounds like you're using a forward declaration. The full class definition needs to be visible before you can use it like that.

Comment: as your error message says: there is no copy constructor....

Comment: @JohannesS. what does it mean?

Comment: No constructor, no copy constructor!

Comment: But I do have a constructor, even 2 of them

Comment: See here (for example): http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/

Comment: @DmitryKazakov: Thank you for including the header! Sadly though, we still can't compile this to recreate your issues. `bitmap` for example, is not defined.

Comment: @DmitryKazakov: My current guess is that `bitmap` is either explicitly not copy constructible, or it has a const member.

Comment: @JohannesS. A copy constructor [should be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_member_functions) automatically generated (although deprecated as a destructor is explicitly defined). But maybe Bill is right, the compiler can't generate the copy constructor because `bitmap` is not copy constructible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message suggests you need to implement the copy constructor `dataCard::dataCard(const dataCard&)`. You need that because for example `vector<dataCard>::push_back()` will copy `dataCard` instances.

When you write the copy constructor, be careful that *all* member variables get copied - in the right way. So an example implementation could be

```
dataCard::dataCard(const dataCard &rhs)
{
    strcpy(name, rhs.name);
    Class = rhs.Class;
    distanceToQuery = rhs.distanceToQuery;
    image = rhs.image; // make sure that this is OK!
}
```

Comment: What about the implicit copy constructor?

Comment: @BillLynch It will not handle `name` in the most probably expected way. This doesn't explain the error though. Good point! On the other hand if you explicitly implement the copy c'tor you will stumble about the *actual* problem. The yet unknown `bitmap` class is a candidate ...

Answer (score 2):

If the compiler does not know the size of a `dataCard` object, it cannot reserve space for it. A pointer however is always a known size so it can reserve space for that.

My guess is that the compiler does not know the exact size of a `dataCard` object. If for example the `bitmap` type object is of variable size, then the compiler would not know what size `dataCard` would be.

Comment: A vector has a fixed size. It is the memory on the heap that the pointer in the vector is pointing to that varies in size.

Comment: Thanks for that, removed the vector example from my answer!

Comment: Also, pardon me if I'm wrong but I don't see how the size of 'dataCard' can be unknown unless it is declared as an opaque pointer to another class that's hidden in another translation unit.

Comment: @Nard: You've got it backwards: https://gist.github.com/sharth/0bf002569de26384e628